# AS3 Load Variables into Textfield from external XML

Tags: php, xml, actionscript-3, variables, echo

I have a php file which outputs an XML data and i also have a swf file coded with AS3 where i want to load the ouput of PHP in.

PHP Code:

```
 echo "<root>
           <Username>" . $xml1 . "</Username>
           <XMLNode2>" . $xml2 . "</XMLNode2>
            <XMLNode3>" . $xml3 . "</XMLNode3>
         </root>";
```

AS3 Code:

```
import flash.events.*;
import flash.net.URLLoader;
import flash.net.URLLoaderDataFormat;
import flash.net.URLRequest;
import flash.net.URLVariables;
import flash.xml.XMLDocument;

var loader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
loader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onLoaded);
loader.load(new URLRequest("playerData.php"));
var variables:URLVariables = new URLVariables();

function onLoaded(evt:Event):void
{
    var xDoc:XMLDocument = new XMLDocument();
    xDoc.ignoreWhite = true;
    loader.resultFormat = "e4x";
    var myXML:XML = loader.data as XML;
    xDoc.parseXML(myXML.toString());
    user_name.text = trace(xDoc.Username);
}
```

This is the error i get in AS3 code:

> Access of possibly undefined property Username through a reference with static type flash.xml:XMLDocument.

Basically those TxtElements are dinamic text (like labels).

Comment: What's the point of the XMLDocument? You code includes no access of a property "Username". Did you post all your code?

Comment: but i still can receive the values....

Comment: i've edited the function, look now..

Comment: and now im getting one more error: Implicit coercion of a value of type void to an unrelated type String.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply do :

```
var loader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
    loader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onLoaded);
    loader.load(new URLRequest('playerData.php'));

function onLoaded(evt:Event):void
{   
    var myXML:XML = new XML(evt.target.data);
    trace(myXML.Username);                           // gives : the value of your php $xml1 var

    userField.text = (myXML.Username).toString();    // we don't need trace() to assing a value to a textfield

}
```

Comment: And then we still nee the line which gives the value of the php variable?

Comment: The variable passed to the trace function (myXML.Username) can also be set as the text property of a text field. You can do whatever you want with it.

Comment: And now im so confused, i didn't get any error, but my "userField" is empty.

Comment: Verify that your xml contains data using `trace(myXML);` or by opening your script (http://your.site/playerData.php) direct on web browser.

Comment: My XML starts' <root> <Username>user</Username> </root> But the textfield is like doesn't see it, why?

Comment: Your textfield should by a dynamic or input textfield.

Comment: is it a dynamic text, and as default has the text: "test123" but when it loads in the browser, the text is like refreshing itself and quickly dissapear (test123), and remains blank. (it doesn't even get the username from xml)....how's that possible?

Comment: I think that you should add a `stop()` in your timeline or there is an error.

Comment: can be added from action script? from this code? There is no error, and i putted this code in the action script but in which layer do i need to put it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/66862/discussion-between-akmozo-and-krazii-kiid).

Answer (score 0):

There's no need for XMLDocument here.
You only need XML class.

Take a look at the XML class example in its documentation:
http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/XML.html#includeExamplesSummary

Here's a an example class that operates on your xml data:

```
package 
{
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    public class FlashTest extends Sprite 
    {
        public function FlashTest() 
        {
            var xml:XML = 
            <root>
                <Username>Paul</Username>
                <XMLNode2> </XMLNode2>
                <XMLNode3></XMLNode3>
            </root>;

            trace("username is: " + xml.Username);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: i've have seen it, but i find it more easier creating a simple output (no XML), so in my php is just:

Comment: print "&uName=$user";
print "&uLevel=$level"; And in my AS3 look here: http://s1.postimg.org/bwlimqwhb/as3.png

Comment: If you are not interested in answers to your questions, please don't ask here. thanks.

Comment: i am interested, i just can't figure it out with the XML type, so your answer with the XML is that in output is: trace("username is: " + xml.Username), but then why you wrote "Paul"? and i don't understand how to put this output to a text field. like: username.text = trace(xml.username).

Comment: I added Paul as a dummy value. Your XML consists of values from php variables. The example I provided runs as is and demonstrates how to access the data in an XML structure.